# TradingView Pinescript - How to find a bar and draw a line through using High/Low

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new to Tradingviwe PineScript. I have an requirement like to draw a horizontal line on specific bar high/low value at specific time.

Eg: 15M time frame 10.00AM bar need to find a High/Low and draw a line through.

Thanks in Advance

Draw a horizontal line using the 15 mins 10 AM bar(High/Low)

Comment: what did you tried so far ? Did you have a script and/or an image of what you are looking for ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Ex", overlay = true)

time_ = timestamp(year=2023,
                 month=04,
                 day=05,
                 hour=10,
                 minute=00)

if time == time_
    line.new(time_, high, time_+60*60*1000, high, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.blue,  extend = extend.right)
    line.new(time_, low, time_+60*60*1000, low, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.green, extend = extend.right)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?